# How to implement the longest common subsequences in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have read [this](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~dpaa111/wiki.files/HuntSzymanski.pdf) paper which explains an algorithm for finding the longest common subsequences. I have problem with coding of creating `matchlist` of Algorithm 2 on page 352. Well, to be exact,

it reads the first string and then it will start second string from the last letter and then will scan and save in decreasing order those letters are qual.

1. First, my problem is how I could save for each letter of list the indices in the linked list? I mean *creating a list for each letter in first string and then a sub-list of it which saves the letters positions in other sting.*
2. Second, I do not know how could I find `k` in the step 3. They key data structure for the described algorithm is an array of *threshold values* `T_(i,k)` defined as:

   `T_(i,k)` = the smallest `j` such that `A[1:i]` and `B[1:j]` contain a common subsequence of length `k`.

Here what is confusing for me is that in the algorithm the `THRESH[]` is sets up as:

```
for i= 1 step 1 until n do
    TRESH[i] := n + 1;
```

which as I understand will set all up to a fixed number. right?

ad then the following line in the Algorithm 2 would be somehow not correct:

```
    find k such that THRESH[k-1] < j <= THRESH[k]
```

Could you please let me know your comments on it. I do really need some hints please!!

Comment: Sorry we're generally not a code writing service.  If you have a specific problem, then pop that in your question.  Good luck!  See [faq]; [ask]; [mcve]

Comment: It would probably be better if you sumarised the problem (exactly what does the "algorithm" do?) too rather than posting a link to a paper

Comment: @Micky I have edited my question. Please do not put on hold. Hope now is clear!

Comment: Thanks for the update Saber.  I wonder if you should post over at Programmers or Computer Science site?  [Check out this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-programmers-se) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it. But please let not be on hold that may someone had an idea about! :)

Comment: Boing! Your question has been re-opened. Gratz :)  See what others think before posting at other site :)

Comment: Aside: Are you coding this as an exercise, or do you actually have a need to find the LCS in production code? If the latter, I believe there are newer algorithms that will serve you better. Google for suffix trees and/or suffix arrays.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It is not an exercise, for my program I have to this algorithm. Because I am told to use it. I know there are faster algs as well.